# Quick one about DOM Reflow

Tags: javascript, dom

If I have an image set to display none;
eg:

```
#myImg {position:absolute;left:100px;top:100px;display:none;}
```

And I move it with Js like so:

```
function Move ()
{var pic=document.getElementById ("myImg");
 myImg.style.left=200+'px';
 myImg.style.top=200+'px';
}
```

Does it cause a reflow even though it's set to 'display:none'?

And what about visibility:hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my previous post I boldly claimed that elements with display: none
>   will not have anything to do with the render tree. IE begs to differ
>   (thanks to dynaTrace folks for pointing that out).
>
> A good way to minimize reflows is to update the DOM tree "offline" out
>   of the live document. One way to do so is to hide the element while
>   updates are taking place and then show it again.

Check out http://www.phpied.com/the-new-game-show-will-it-reflow/